# On Change event is not firing after first change in lightning:select

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I used lightning:select like this:

```
<lightning:select label="op:" aura:id="opid" name="fop" 
                  onchange="{!c.onchangeev}"
                  disabled="{!v.dis}" required="true">
   <option selected="" value="">--Select operator--</option>
       <aura:iteration items="{!v.oplist}" var="item" indexVar="key">
              option value="{!item.key}">{!item.value}</option>
       </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

My issue: on change event is fired after i select option after second time. Anyone have idea why?

Comment: whats the issue you are facing

Comment: As I said: event is fired after selecting an option for the second time.
Lets say that I have picklist with options: 
--Select operator--
Low
Medium
High
I choose low and onchange event is not fired. But if I choose Medium or High it is fired without problem.

Comment: can you provide your controller method as well?

Comment: for what? event is not fired at all so method is not executing it could be even:
function onchangeev(component, event, helper) { console.log("yo");}